# Send Email Notification Before 90 days

Tags: email-template, contracts

Can any one help me out on this?

We have a custom object as Contract Role and it has ROLE as a picklist field which has values as "SA" ,"EB","OR" ETC.It has a master detail relationship with Contract.

Now i would like to send an email notification to Contract role before 90 days from the contract end date whos role is " SA ".This notification should be sent to the "SA Role".

Any example or suggestions .

ANY HELP VERY MUCH APPRECIATED.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma :Thanks for the response.The workflow is set , but  i got stucked in role ..how to send email notification for the Role which is SA.This role is a picklist field at custom object.Any customization should be done ,instead of configuration.

Comment: You just need to define the entry criteria to the Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use Workflow time trigger for this. On creation of record set this trigger to before 90 days of expiry date and it will solve your problem.

[image: WF Time Trigger]

Comment: In enter criteria define where  role is SA.

Comment: :I didnt get ur point.Any example very much appreciated.

Comment: set your WF to run on insert and in rule define if role = S,A, Now create a time trigger before 90 days of your date and check.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always have one and only one of each role, you can use process builder or flow to set a field on the contract record for each recipient role user or email, then fire standard workflow email alerts to the recipient.

Better would be to use flow to send the email. You can use a collection element to store a list of emails, and can send the email from flow or use an email alert from within the flow.

Since the role info is on child object, there is no way to send via workflow on child when parent is edited.

I suppose you could use process builder to update a date field on the child records, and then use an email alert from the child records.  Haven't tried it but should work.

Comment: :Thanks for your response.I dont have an idea of process builder.If possible can you help me out with an example.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Actually just saw that your child object is master detail.  So you can use a cross object field update to set the field on the parent.  Create an email field for each recipient type on parent.  Then use a workflow rule to populate the value when child record is created or edited.